# DateFormatter formats string using incorrect time zone

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

#### Preconditions

Set time zone GMT+13 (Fale, Tokeleau) in phone's settings.

#### Implementation

```
extension Date {
    func formatForDto() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZ"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 320756400) // which is 1980-03-01 11:00:00 UTC
let result = date.formatForDto()
```

#### Result

`result = "1980-03-01 00:00:00 -1100"` instead of `1980-03-02 00:00:00 +1300` (11:00 + 13).

In debugger when I check what's inside `dateFormatter.timeZone` I get a correct result:

```
(lldb) po dateFormatter.timeZone
▿ Optional<TimeZone>
  ▿ some : Pacific/Fakaofo (current)
    - identifier : "Pacific/Fakaofo"
    - kind : "current"
    ▿ abbreviation : Optional<String>
      - some : "GMT+13"
    - secondsFromGMT : 46800
    - isDaylightSavingTime : false
```

#### Expected result

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1411406-timezone):

> DateFormatter.timeZone - If unspecified, the system time zone is used.

My function should return `1980-03-02 00:00:00 +1300`.

#### Workaround

What's more interesting, when I set timeZone manually to:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 13 * 60 * 60)
```

Then it returns as expected `1980-03-02 00:00:00 +1300`.

#### Question

So why without `timeZone` set it doesn't work as claimed in the documentation and does not take into account system's timezone? Is it a bug in SDK?

Comment: No, I still don't get it. You say "I get". How? You write `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 320756400).formatForDto() // 1980-03-01 11:00:00 UTC`, showing us the output in a comment. Then you turn around and say "I get `1980-03-01 00:00:00 -1100`". But you just told us that isn't what you get. So what does "I get" mean here? — This is not a big ask; all you have to do is provide an actual reproducible case. Just show code that allows us to see what you're seeing.

Comment: This comment refers only to Date, not to formatForDto output, my mistake. I updated this part. You've got now reproducible case.

Comment: Okay, so you are complaining because you see this date-time both as `1980-03-01 11:00:00 UTC`
and as `1980-03-01 00:00:00 -1100`. Why? They are the same date-time. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to have `1980-03-02 00:00:00 +1300` as a result of this function.

Comment: Then you need to specify the time zone in the formatter, exactly as you do in the "workaround".

Comment: So this whole question is about that, why it doesn't work according to documentation

Comment: Well, the problem in my view is still your format. First you suppressed the time zone altogether; then you used `ZZ`, which I think does not do what you think it does. Change your oddball time zone format `ZZ` to `ZZZZ` and you will see what you expect to see.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that you still have not given a reproducible example. You say `let result = date.formatForDto() // 1980-03-01 00:00:00 -1100` but that is misleading, because `result` just sits there like a bump on a log, so where does the value in your comment come from? If you would use a `print` statement, you would see what `result` _is_, but you don't. So _how do you know_? I'm a little worried that the answer is you're doing all this in a playground...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is very interesting, because it turned out that it's caused by timezone: `Fale, Tokeleau` which I assumed is **GMT+13**, but according to [Time Zone in Fakaofo, Tokelau](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/tokelau/fakaofo) this timezone before 30 Dec, 2011 was **GMT-11**.

That's why for my example `1980-03-01 11:00:00 UTC` a different offset was applied and that's why it worked with `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 13 * 60 * 60)` which specifies exact offset instead of time zone.

Therefore If I check my code with date:

- `2012-03-01 11:00:00 UTC` it returns `1980-03-02 00:00:00 +1300`
- `1980-03-01 11:00:00 UTC` it returns `1980-03-01 00:00:00 -1100`

Comment: So it's not a defect. Everything worked just as it should have. It's all due to a change in this specific timezone some time in the past.